# Displaying Counter Value from Equation Tag

Tags: cross-referencing, counters, tags

I am trying to create the following, but haven't been able to find anything here or elsewhere online...

I want to create an equation with a custom counter and then call the value of the counter when it was used in that equation. For example consider this.

```
\newcounter{opt}
\[
    ax + b = c
\refstepcounter{opt}
\label{eq:1}
\]
\ref{eq:1}
```

This final `\ref` call produces the value `1`, as I desire. However, I'd like to tag the equation with a non-standard tag, eg `\tag*{$(P_1)$}`. I can do this as follows.

```
\newcounter{opt}
\[
    ax + b = c
\refstepcounter{opt}
\label{eq:1}
\tag*{$(P_\theopt)$}
\]
\ref{eq:1}
```

This gives the correct tag, however now the `\ref` call produces `(P_1)`, instead of just `1`.

How can I adapts this so that I get the desired tag *and* I can reference the equation and get the value of the counter?

---

This, "[Referring to label and value of counter at that point](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227678/referring-to-label-and-value-of-counter-at-that-point?rq=1)", is a highly related post. It's doing something a bit more in-depth than I am trying to do, and I can't understand what's going on well enough to adapt it...

---

If it helps, the context is the following. I have an optimisation problem, and I want to label two equations `(P_1)` and `(C_1)` using the same counter `opt`. I then want to call this as `(P,C)_1`; I was going to do this by writing `(P,C)_\ref{eq:1}`.

I suppose, all I actually want to be able to do is to write a different thing in the brackets `()` on the equation line to what I `\ref` produces.

If there's a better way of doing this, I'm all ears!

Comment: If the equation is labeled (P<sub>1</sub>), why should the reference be just 1?

Comment: Sorry, if I wasn't clear. I'm not questioning *why* the above does what it does -- indeed, it's labelled `(P_1)`, as you say. However, I want to be able to *call* from the label just the value `1`. This is what I can't work out how to do. \\ Hopefully the context I've added makes it clear! :)

Comment: Do you want, for certain equations, a counter independent from the general equation counter, or only change the way the general  counter is displayed?

Comment: I'd like this whole part to be separate from the general equation counter

Comment: But if the two equations are different, you can't refer  them with the same value of the counter!

Comment: So I just don't step the counter between the two equations. I have pairs of equations. I added some context earlier: ther eyou can see I have two equations that I want to label `(P_1)` and `(C_1)` *using the same counter* (which will be taking the value `1` at this point). I'll then have another pair later, which will be labelled `(P_2)` and `(C_2)`, and so on. I want to be able to call the subscript from the tag, not the whole tag.

Comment: I suppose, all I actually want to be able to do is to write a different thing in the brackets `()` on the equation line to what I `\ref` produces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a protected command, so it will be written as such in the `.aux` file and you can define it to act differently in different contexts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xparse}

\newcounter{xtag}
\NewDocumentCommand{\xtag}{sm}{%
  \IfBooleanF{#1}{\refstepcounter{xtag}}%
  \tag{\choosetag{#2}{\thextag}}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\choosetag}{mm}
 {
  \bool_if:NTF \l_samt_choosetag_ref_bool
   {
    #2
   }
   {
    $\mathrm{#1}\sb{#2}$
   }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\xref}{m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \bool_set_true:N \l_samt_choosetag_ref_bool
  \ref{#1}
  \group_end:
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\xeqref}{om}
 {
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
   {
    \eqref{#2}
   }
   {
    \textnormal{(#1)}$\sb{\xref{#2}}$
   }
 }

\bool_new:N \l_samt_choosetag_ref_bool
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
1=1 \xtag{P}  \label{a} \\
2=2 \xtag*{C} \label{b} \\
3=3 \xtag{P}  \label{c}
\end{gather}

\xeqref{a} or \xeqref[P,C]{a}

\xeqref{c}

\end{document}
```

The command `\xtag` advances the counter, but the variant `\xtag*` doesn't.

[image]

Comment: Grazie mille! That's exactly what I wanted :) -- I have no idea what the `group` and `bool` stuff means, but I understand the rest... mostly! There are a couple of other situations I wanted a similar thing for, and I should be able to adapt your answer to those, so thanks very much! :)

Comment: The `\choosetag` command changes its behavior according to truth or falsehood of the boolean; in `\xref` the boolean is set to true, so only the second argument is used. I fixed a slip.

Comment: Ok, thanks. And yeah, I noticed the change -- what difference did it make?

Comment: @SamT You'd realize it if typesetting `\xeqref` in a theorem statement (or, in general, in italic context).

Comment: Ah, because it was forcing it to be upright?